# How to display Bottom Navigation bar in iOS and Top Navigation bar in Android (NativeScript Angular)?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I used the `tns-template-tab-navigation-ng` to generate the template. My goal is to make a whatsApp clone and in iOS it's bottom navigation bar and in android its Top nav. I would like to know how to display it as TopNav in android.

[Link for template](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/app-templates/app-templates.html#tabs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two templates:

app.component.ios.html

```
<BottomNavigation>
  ...
</BottomNavigation>
```

app.component.android.html

```
<Tabs>
  ...
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Yeh, that's the way i did it. Thanks